# how to remove migration

Tags: ubuntu, process, migration

I recently got a problem on ubuntu 12.04.1
i've got a process named migration (PID 6)

```
`$ ps -edf | grep migration
root         6     2 57 Jun25 ?        1-04:08:02 [migration/0]
root         8     2 36 Jun25 ?        17:48:58 [migration/1]
root        13     2 47 Jun25 ?        23:27:49 [migration/2]
root        17     2 51 Jun25 ?        1-01:23:39 [migration/3]`

`USER     PID %CPU
root       6 56.7 migration/0
root      17 51.2 migration/3
root      13 47.2 migration/2
root       8 35.9 migration/1`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google took me here, wanted to know what it was. But these are kernel threads responsible for moving threads between CPU threats.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/85463/high-cpu-usage-without-a-process-to-blame-what-is-migration-x

Comment: I recently moved to Debian Testing(jessie). Migration is still there but he don't take so many cpu usage. EDIT: Migration cannot be removed because a believe it's a part of the kernel